# Wiggle in the current source of an emittter follower amplifier

Tags: ltspice, power-amplifier, emitter-follower

This has been bugging me for days. I still don't understand why the book says the current I through Q1 remains constant when there is a varying input signal at the base of  Q1. Some peeps here also say that it is constant. I understand that Q2 is like a constant current source but when I try simulating it in LTspice the current through Q2 is not constant. Take note that the simulation is for RL open.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know why do you see a "small" change in the transistor current in LTspice? Also, can you explain to me why do you think that current should change? If you have a constant current source in the emitter?

Comment: Let me try, you change the vbe of Q1, this translates to a change in collector current of Q1 as well. No?

Comment: @Paumdrdo If you are able, create a custom model for \$Q_2\$ (in the LTspice diagram) and use VA=10k as one of the parameters. I think you'll see a difference in the effects. In short, a part of the variation you see is due to the Early Effect. Another part is, of course, because your input signal is wrecking havoc. Add a DC offset of 5 V and use a peak voltage of 3 V, instead.

Comment: @Paumdrdo But if the emitter current is held constant by an external constant current source and we are using ideal BJT (no Early Effect), then the Vbe voltage will not change at all (Vbe will be constant). But the voltage at the emitter will swing in the rhythm of an input signal and it will be Equal Ve = Vin - Vbe

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the answer here, yet, that you should be seeing. (Yes, BJTs vary all over the place, one to another. But that does *not* answer why LTspice shows you what it did, which uses an exactly-the-same-every-time BJT model.)

There are three important problems (at least) with your simulation:

1. No accounting for the Early Effect in your thinking or testing.
2. No accounting for base drive affecting the mirrored collector current.
3. "Signal" doesn't properly keep the devices in active mode.

So let's draw up a schematic that fixes #2 and #3 so that you can focus on the effects of #1 and see it in action.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7JS7S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The addition of \$I_1\$ and \$Q_4\$ ensures that there will be a rather constant \$1\:\text{mA}\$ into \$Q_1\$'s collector. \$Q_4\$ is tasked with supplying the base current for both \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$, so that it doesn't subtract from \$Q_1\$'s collector current. And the use of \$I_1\$ gives us a perfect current source, which is better than a resistor because we don't know the collector voltage of \$Q_1\$.

The use of a DC sweep from \$2\:\text{V}\$ to \$8\:\text{V}\$ ensures that \$Q_3\$ isn't either smashed up against the \$10\:\text{V}\$ rail or else smashed down against \$Q_2\$'s collector. So this keeps things on an "even keel" so to speak.

Once this is done, we can now run this:

[image]

And here you can now clearly see the Early Effect.

Answer (score 1):

The current varies between 98 and 112 mA i.e. it is 105 mA +/- 7 mA and, as far as any reasonable estimate of power consumption to any reasonable degree of accuracy the current is largely constant at 105 mA: -

[image]

BJT's are not very accurate and, trying to do accurate estimates of this or that is really a pointless exercise to any degree better than +/- 5%. It is very reasonable to assume that the current is constant for the sake of calculating power dissipation and, if necessary, play safe by adding another 10% of power.